# Gensim needs a C compiler?

Tags: python, compilation, word2vec

Sorry that I don't have enough reputation to post images.

The main problem is that it tells me that I need to install a C compiler and reinstall gensim or the train will be slow, and in fact it is really slow.

I have installed mingw32, Visual Studio 2008, and have added the mingw32 environment variable to my path.

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: please upload a picture and post the link in your question, somebody will edit your question and insert the picture.

Comment: Instead of posting a screenshot you should post 1. the command you're trying to run, and 2. the full logs & error message you receive. That is just plain text, it doesn't need to be a screenshot.

Comment: i have also struggled with his problem and have not been able to find a way to install C compiler on windows. I will be watching this question, in case you guys find anything. i thought there would be at least one good simple tutorial on how to do this on windows.

Answer (score 1):

Just as you I installed mingw32 and added `MinGW\bin` to my `PATH` variable. I then uninstalled gensim with `pip uninstall gensim` and tried reinstalling with `pip install gensim`. That however gave the same warning so instead I downloaded `gensim-0.12.3.tar.gz` from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gensim#downloads). I unzipped the archive and also the inner one, opened a cmd window in the folder and ran `python setup.py install` to install gensim. Now I could already from the output see that it could see the MinGW install. It installed correctly and I could run gensim without the warning and much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to user1151923, after adding `MinGW\bin` to my path variable and uninstalling\reinstalling gensim through pip, I still received the same warning message. I ran the following code to fix this problem (installed gensim from conda).

`pip uninstall gensim`

`conda install gensim`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried many solutions, but none of them worked except degrading to gensim version 3.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

When I installed it from conda-forge then I obtained a version that is already compiled and fast:
conda install -c conda-forge gensim